# Gitlab 7.3.2 Permission Denied (publickey)

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-7

I just made a fresh installation of Gitlab 7.3.2 on a private server. Then I created a new project, a new user with a valid ssh key.

When I am trying to clone the test project, it throws me the Permission denied (publickey). 
In the previous version I had to check the settings of the /home/git folder or something like that but now this folder does not exists.

Any idea on how I could solve this please ?

```
ssh -vT git@git.xxx.xx
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/xxx/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git.xxx.xx [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA b0:a2:51:5b:b9:a7:e9:be:0c:5c:0b:51:e1:c8:c9:5e
debug1: Host 'git.xxx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: do an `ls -l /home/xxx/.ssh/` and see what permissions are set. can the process read the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok my mess, git was not authorized to connect via ssh. I updated the ssh configuration to add more security ...

Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

If other folks find this question and are having the same problem but the authorized_keys file is in tact and local keys seem to be fine (or, as in my case, everything was fine until a yum update and reboot), try this:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also pushing to the `https` url instead of the `ssh` this can save you lot of trouble - example how to use this:

`git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/someuser/algorithm-excercises.git`

instead of:

`git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:someuser/algorithm-excercises.git